# Java to HTML/JavaScript converter?

Tags: java, javascript, html, web, applet

I wrote a Swing-based desktop application (kind of a small calculator), and I've been asked to convert it to a web application. I have the applet version of this as well. But Applets aren't an option. I lack the time or experience necessary to do the conversion by hand.

Is there any software that can help me convert my desktop app or applet to a web app? I cannot buy one, so free/opensource or trial versions will be good. Also, I'm not looking for a runtime converter (like AjaxSwing) - I want to statically convert the source code. Which means, I just need the converted HTML+JAVASCRIPT (or whatever which I do not have to install to run like Java plugin. and not server based) code of my Java code.

Comment: Perhaps [Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)? See also [Is Google Web Toolkit similar to AWT and Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407506/is-google-web-toolkit-similar-to-awt-and-swing).